# JavaScript Loop doesn't exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, browser, infinite

I've tried everything I can think of.

I'm building a sort of chat bot for IMVU, using injected JavaScript on the IMVU mobile website. I have a loop to crawl the messages received, and search for certain key terms, like a message beginning with a slash (/) to indicate a command to the bot.

When certain commands are used, I have a problem that the bot seems to get stuck in the loop, almost as if the index of the for loop is being modified inside the loop. The code is included below.

If you need more, ask, and if you find something that might be causing the problem, please let me know. I'm at my wit's end.

Just for a note: jQuery is properly injected, all my variables are there, no errors in the debug console, and running under Chrome 41.0.2272.101m on Windows 7 x64.

```
function verifyCommand() {
  if (document.getElementsByClassName("message-list-item").length > last_cmd_count && !processing_commands) {
    var new_length = $('.message-list .message-list-item').length;
    console.log("Begin processing commands... ** SYSTEM LOCK **");
    console.log(new_length);
    for (var i = last_cmd_count; i < (new_length); i++) {
      processing_commands = true;
      try {
        var callinguser = $('.message-list .message-list-item .header .username .username-text')[i].innerText.replace("Guest_", "");
        var messagetext = $('.message-list .message-list-item .message .message-text')[i].innerText
        if (callinguser != "USERNAME REMOVED") {
          if (messagetext.substr(0, 1) == "/") {
            if (strContains(callinguser, "IMVU User")) {
              die();
            }
            processCommand(messagetext.substr(1), callinguser);
          } else {
            if (messagetext.toLowerCase().indexOf('roomgreet') > -1 || messagetext.toLowerCase().indexOf('room greet') > -1) {
              if (detectFlirt()) {
                sendMsgRaw('Please do not hit on me, ' + callinguser + '.');
                if (!isAdmin(callinguser)) {
                  logIdiot(callinguser);
                }
              } else if (strContains(messagetext, 'what is ')) {
                sendMsgRaw('Please use /solve or /advsolve for math.');
              } else {
                if (callinguser != "USERNAME REMOVED") {
                  ident();
                }
              }
            }
            if (strContains(messagetext, 'free') && strContains(messagetext, 'credits') && strContains(messagetext, 'http://')) {
              sendMsgFrom("*** SCAM ALERT ***", callinguser);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (ex) {} finally {}
    }
    processing_commands = false;
    last_cmd_count = new_length;
    console.log("Finish processing commands... ** SYSTEM FREE **");
    if (monitoring) {
      verifyUserMessageCount();
    }
  }
}
```

HTML of the IMVU Mobile messages can be found at http://common.snftech.tk/imvu/roomgreet-html-sample.htm

Comment: What happens if you change your for loop like this `for (var i = last_cmd_count; i < new_length; i++) ` ?

Comment: The way this is written, we would have to know what all of the mentioned functions do, to be able to help. Most importantly though, do any of your functions that get called in there call  `verifyCommand()` themselves? If so, I would start anywhere that 1st function is called.

Comment: @DelightedD0D, no recursion in my code. Checked. It's only called by `setInterval(verifyCommand,1000);` at the end of the script file, which is outside of a function itself. No go on adding var, can't believe I forgot it though, leaving it there. That's why you don't write late at night @vsync, if you have nothing useful to contribute, don't comment please.

Comment: I would recommend setting a breakpoint on `processing_commands = true;` . Each time this line gets called, take a look at `i` and see if the value is incremented as expected. Once you see the value change unexpectedly, make a note of the last valid value and start the loop over again. When that last valid value for `i` comes around, watch the code all the way through your logic and you should be able to find where things start to go wrong

Comment: @DelightedD0D, it behaves as though `last_cmd_count` is never being updated, which implies in my head that there's an error causing it to crash out of the loop, but nothing shows in my debug console other than something that's only jQuery arguing with IMVU's main handler script on how to use something it's got. I'm still stumped.

Comment: Well there's a `die` (whatever that is) right there. Are you sure it's not where it dies?

Comment: The commands you are trying to process, are they all the text in the `$('.message-list .message-list-item .message .message-text')` elements?

Comment: @sebnukem, `die()` is the exit function that shows a js alert to stop execution in the event of a loop like this, that is currently disabled with the exception of sending a message in chat stating `***CRITICAL FAILURE***`. @DelightedD0D, yes, otherwise the command throws an error which is caught, sending a message in chat saying that the command was not understood/used properly.

Comment: Can you show us the html for 2 or 3 of your messages, that is the full html for each message including the `.username-text` bits?

Comment: @DelightedD0D, too long for original post and comments, added a link to the HTML on my server. Five messages, three system generated and two user messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your function to use `each()` to loop through each element instead of the loop you have. Once an element has been processed, add a "processed" class to the element so we dont look at them again later. This should be more stable than forcing our logic to keep up with what ones have been processed already.

[Here is a jsFiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/jb0e6L7u/3/), throw in the html from your page that actually causes the problem and see if it still occurs

```
function verifyCommand() {
  //fixed some logic in here
  if ($(".message-list-item").length > last_cmd_count && !processing_commands) {
    processing_commands = true; // you should set this immediately 
    var new_length = $('.message-list-item').length;
    console.log("Begin processing commands... ** SYSTEM LOCK **");
    console.log('Last command count: '+ last_cmd_count +', New Length: '+new_length);
    var newMessages = $('.message-list-item:not(.processed)'); // get all of the message elements that do not have the class "processed" 
    // loop through each of the message elements
    newMessages.each(function(index, element){
         console.log('Processing new element at index '+index );
         try {
              var callinguser = $(this).find('.username-text').text().replace("Guest_", "");
              var messagetext = $(this).find('.message-text').text();
              $(this).addClass('processed'); // add processed class to the element so we know not to process it again later  
              if (callinguser != "RoomGreet") {
                if (messagetext.match(/^\//)) {
                  if (callinguser.match(/IMVU User/)) {
                    die();
                  }
                  processCommand(messagetext.substr(1), callinguser);
                }
                else {
                    if (detectFlirt(messagetext)) {
                      if (!isAdmin(callinguser)) {
                        sendMsgRaw('Please do not hit on me, ' + callinguser + '.');
                        logIdiot(callinguser);
                      }
                    }
                    else if (messagetext.match('what is ')) {
                      sendMsgRaw('Please use /solve or /advsolve for math.');
                    }
                    else {
                      if (callinguser != "Nezzle" && !isAdmin(callinguser)) {
                        ident();
                      }
                    }
                  if (strContains(messagetext,"imvu") && strContains(messagetext,"credits") && strContains(messagetext,"http://")) {
                    sendMsgFrom("*** SCAM ALERT ***", callinguser);
                  }
                }
              }
         }
         catch (ex) {
             console.log('caught error');
         } 
         finally {
         }
    });
    last_cmd_count = new_length;
    console.log("Finish processing commands... ** SYSTEM FREE **");
    processing_commands = false;
    if (monitoring) {
      verifyUserMessageCount();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem does indeed still occur. The problematic command is /commands which is to show the usage of all the commands. It was behaving like it was responding to the commands it sent in chat, so I reset a couple of things you changed to the way I had them before, simply because I knew they worked. [Log is available on my website](http://common.snftech.tk/imvu/roomgreet-output.log), includes the revised verifyCommand function and the entire output log from Chrome's debugging console. I have an Adobe Connect room I can use for sharing and voice comm if you prefer that, we can set meeting.

Comment: Another reason I know the problem is in the `verifyCommand` function is because I can call `processCommand(cmd,user)` directly through the Chrome debugging console (which I also aliased as `cmdx(cmd,user)`) and it doesn't cause this problem, it behaves normally.

Comment: When the error occurs on your page, throw all of the  generated html from your page into the fiddle as I made it. Does the issue still occur? If so click update so the html is saved and give me the new address so I can take a look at it

Comment: You say that when you call `processCommand(cmd,user)` manually, it works. I'm sure it does, as you are undoubtedly calling it  and passing in expected values. It's far more likely that `processCommand(cmd,user)` , or some other function in there, is getting called in your production environment and passing in _unexpected_ values and causing your error. Though no such error that I can imagine would cause an infinite loop like you described. The only thing that would cause such a loop would be if your function somehow calls itself (recursion) and gets stuck there

Comment: or the value your loop checks against is changing unexpectedly

Comment: Sometime between yesterday when I tried and today when I tried, something is different that it is stable now. I'm not sure what it is, but you were the only really helpful user, SO could use some more people like you, as opposed to vsync up there with nothing to do but criticise my code style. Yes, I know my code is crap. But it's mine. Again, thank you, DelightedD0D. I've put a shoutout to you in the code, and if you like, you can email me at bobsklar12@gmail.com and I'll send you a jsFiddle link that shows the finalised stable code.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is this

```
if (messagetext.substr(0,1) == "/") {
```

if the user has a space in front of the "/" then it will not interpret as a command so you need to process

```
var messagetext =  $('.message-list .message-list-item .message .message-text')[i].innerText
```

remove all white space from message text like this

```
messagetext.text().replace(" ", "");
```

you should also have more error catching in

```
if (messagetext.substr(0,1) == "/") {
```

Comment: Why would this cause the loop to continue infinitely?

Comment: in your 
if (messagetext.substr(0,1) == "/") {
     ...do stuff if command
}else{
     ...else if not command do stuff
       but what if it is a command but formatted wrong ??
       program says I don't know what to do so ill do it again
     so you should have a catch for this like  
    if( messagetext.indexOf("/")>0){;// this is a command we missed}
}

Comment: Why would that cause another run through the loop? I would just hit the else statement and process it that way or throw an error. That wouldn't cause an infinite loop.

Comment: this for loop is wrong it never exits the loop 
for (i = last_cmd_count; i < (new_length); i++) {
if your going to use a for loop this part i = last_cmd_count needs to be a constant like for(i=0;
replace your for loop with a for each loop read up on how to do this at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: all together though this code is poorly written... i would start from scratch

Comment: you do realize I am not the OP right? : )    I was just asking why you thought that line was causing an infinite loop. It seems to me that if `if (messagetext.substr(0, 1) == "/") ` fails, the code would simply fall into the else statement where it would either get processed incorrectly or cause an error if the code wasnt expecting that value.

Comment: you just answered your own question  " it would either get processed incorrectly or cause an error if the code wasn't expecting that value" most likely not letting the loop exit sometimes. but i would still go for the for each loop it is a better way to go in this case because you are working with an array. it would clean up a lot of the problem you have with this current code.

Comment: again, this is not my question : )

Comment: The command will be ignored if the message does NOT start with a slash, which is my intention. Not looking for how to clean up the code, not looking for criticism on the code that makes a degree of sense in my head. I'm very particular about my style.

Comment: Another point, it would make it very hard to convey how to use commands within the system if you couldn't say "use /rules to read the room rules" in the chat without the bot responding. And on IMVU, triggers can be used in messages by typing things like /dance in the middle of your message, in which case we don't want the bot to respond with its own dance command.